# como agrupar los resultados de un mismo registro en una consulta a 3 tablas relacionadas con INNER JOIN (mysql/php)

Tags: php, sql

Buen día todos.
Tengo estas 3 tablas relacionadas por llaves foraneas y necesito que por medio de una consulta pueda agrupar por persona(Patrocinadores) los patrocinios que tiene, con el nombre del patrocinio(Que esta en la tabla tipo_eventos en su columna tipo_evento)

las Tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TENGO la siguiente función que consulta las 3 tablas pero muestra repetidos los registros de la tabla "patrocinadores", (con un print_r($lista)):

```
static function listarPatrociniosxPatrocinador(){
    $mysqli=conectar();
    $sentencia=$mysqli->query("SELECT patrocinadores.nombre_patrocinador, 
    patrocinios.id_tipo_evento, tipo_eventos.tipo_evento
     FROM patrocinadores 
     INNER JOIN patrocinios ON patrocinios.id_patrocinador=patrocinadores.id_patrocinador
     INNER JOIN tipo_eventos ON tipo_eventos.cod_tipo=patrocinios.id_tipo_evento");
    $lista=$sentencia->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    return $lista;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**lo que quiero lograr es que me muestre agrupados los "patrocinios" por cada "patrocinador" algo asi como:**

Array ( [nombre_patrocinador] => RODRIGO VILLA [id_tipo_evento] => 8, 14 [tipo_evento] => ENFERMERÍA,
HERIDAS COMPLEJAS )

Intente hacerlo con "Group by" pero no resulta solo muestra un patrocinio por registro y no se si lo estoy aplicando bien:

```
$sentencia=$mysqli->query("SELECT patrocinadores.nombre_patrocinador, 
    patrocinios.id_tipo_evento, tipo_eventos.tipo_evento
     FROM patrocinadores 
     INNER JOIN patrocinios ON patrocinios.id_patrocinador=patrocinadores.id_patrocinador
     INNER JOIN tipo_eventos ON tipo_eventos.cod_tipo=patrocinios.id_tipo_evento
     GROUP BY patrocinadores.id_patrocinador ASC");
```

Puedo realizarlo con código PHP concatenandolos en un foreach o con 3 consultas por aparte pero el rendimiento es muy lento( los registros pueden llegar hacer muchos) y queria saber si se podia agrupar desde la misma consulta para mejorar rendimiento... Ante todo muchas gracias por su tiempo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que tu intento con GROUP BY esta incompleto, para obtener el resultado que deseas complementa tu consulta con **GROUP_CONTAT** de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT  patrocinadores.nombre_patrocinador, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(patrocinios.id_tipo_evento) AS idTipoEvento,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tipo_eventos.tipo_evento) AS tipoEvento
FROM patrocinadores 
 INNER JOIN patrocinios ON patrocinios.id_patrocinador=patrocinadores.id_patrocinador
INNER JOIN tipo_eventos ON tipo_eventos.cod_tipo=patrocinios.id_tipo_evento
GROUP BY patrocinadores.id_patrocinador ASC
```

Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, era la solución que buscaba, quería preguntarte si se puede especificar como concatenar los resultados con otros caracteres ya que por defecto lo hace con comas y después lo estoy exportando a un csv, no sé si se puede desde la consulta y si no para hacerlo desde PHP... De igual forma muchas gracias 

Comment: Por su puesto, añadiendo __SEPARATOR__ seguidamente del separador deseado:  GROUP_CONCAT(patrocinios.id_tipo_evento SEPARATOR '@' )